# Exception: Cannot import pyOpenSSL

Tags: python, windows, ansible, pyopenssl, winrm

I'm attempting to get an ansible script working to simply ping WINDOWS guests from an ansible control server, here are my files :

**hosts.yml**

```
[winsrvrs]
server.domain.com

**group_vars/all.yml**
ansible_user: domain\\userID
ansible_password: password
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore


When attempting to run ansible-playbook -i hosts play.yml i get the following error: 

Exception: Cannot import pyOpenSSL

fatal: [wstnm.nml.com]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall both `WINRM and PYOPENSSL` along with all supporting dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If your ansible control machine is on Ubuntu, install these dependencies first:

```
$sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
$pip install cryptography
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `pip install pyopenssl --upgrade`

Comment: Worked... that was an incredibly frustrating situation, thanks for providing me the answer!

Comment: and what if the module was installed?